# Which R function does NORM.S.DIST equal to?

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel calculation which uses the NORM.S.DIST function but I can't find it's counterpart in R.
In Excel:

```
 NORM.S.DIST((0.570 - 0.554) / SQRT(0.289^2 + 0.369^2), TRUE) = 0.514
```

In R:

```
?(0.570 - 0.554) / sqrt(0.289^2 + 0.369^2)
```

I have tried with pnorm() and qnorm() but they don't do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pnorm()` *does* do the job:

`pnorm((0.570 - 0.554) / sqrt(0.289^2 + 0.369^2))` = 0.514